# I cannot get a ReactDOM.render from React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm beginnner and I create my first app in React JS  this is my code now:

```js
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;

}
function formatCountry(user) {
  
    return user.country;
  
}


//this is my objet base of the user
const user = {
  firstName: 'Simon',
  lastName: 'willians',
  country:'USA'};

const element = <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>;
const element2 = <h1>Country,{formatCountry(user)}!</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

I create this app follow this [tutorial of Facebook React JS](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Okay I created a object with name **user** I return this object from  **formatName** and **formatCountry** and the element of the object whatever exist in the object .

I try call country too in this sentence:

```js
const element2 = <h1>Country,{formatCountry(user)}!</h1>;
```

any expert in React JS could tell me where is my error or where I mistakes?

Comment: You need a single root component that gets rendered via ReactDOM.render(). That root component would then contain your `element` and `element2` components.

Comment: this way :  function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName + ' '+  user.country;
}   it working well

Comment: can you see my now , here : https://codepen.io/gilbertoquinteroA/pen/xzQovM?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are trying to render same element, not `element` and `element2`. Secondly, if you render elements like that, only the last one is being rendered in the DOM. You need some wrapper element and inside this wrapper you will have your elements.

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

function formatCountry(user) {
    return user.country;
}

const user = {
    firstName: 'Simon',
    lastName: 'willians',
    country:'USA'};

const element2 = <h1>Country,{formatCountry(user)}!</h1>;

const element = ( 
  <div>
      <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>
      {element2}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Maybe more elegantly:

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

function formatCountry(user) {

    return user.country;

}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez',
  country:'USA',
};

const userCountry = <h1>Country,{formatCountry(user)}!</h1>;

const userName = ( 
  <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>
);

const element = (
  <div>
      {userName}
      {userCountry}
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I understand the code  but why you call this part : </h1>
    
   {element2}
    
  </div> I did not understand this part

Comment: Because JSX elements need to be wrapped in one parent, wrapping element. I looked the documentation but this is not mentioned and I think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Babel. The tutorial you followed uses Babel to compile JavaScript under the hood.

1) Add Babel script to your head tag

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

2) Add **type="text/babel"** to the script tag where you wrote your code.

```
<script type="text/babel">
   function formatName(user) {
       return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
   }
   const user = {
       firstName: 'Harper',
       lastName: 'Pereez',
   };

   const element = <h1>Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>;
   ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById('root')
</script>
```